# In US, what happens if you owe money to doctor and forget about it?

Tags: criminal-law, constitutional-law, medical, finance, collections

If I owe money to some family physician or a dentist, but because my phone number has changed I was not able to be contacted by them.

1. What does a doctor/dentist do if I owe them about $500 or so ?
2. Is there are short cut, then dialing every single doctor I visited?

Answer (score 1):

It's sent to collections like any other business would do if you do not pay them.

Edit:  I'm aware of several charities that will work with people who can't ordinarily afford to pay their bills to get them some relief, but this is usually reserved for ER patients in so far as I'm aware.

Comment: Is this answer meant for USA? double checking